# Defining a complex ability using CanCanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, cancan, cancancan

In my data model:

`Company has_many offices`

`Employee has_many offices, through: :employee_office` (this is how I am allowing Company administrators to permission employees for certain offices and not others)

`Office has_many appointments` and 
`Appointment belongs_to office`

I would like to define an ability using `CanCanCan` that allows an `Employee` to perform actions on an `Appointment` only if the `Employee` works at the `Office` the `Appointment` was made at.

Something like this psuedocode:

`Employee` `can :manage Appointment, Employee.offices.include?(Appointment.office)`

This is what I have so far:

```
class EmployeeAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(employee)
    can :read,      Company,        :id => employee.company.id
    can :read,      Office,         :id => employee.company.id
    #I'd like to include the above psuedocode here, but I'm not sure how to structure it
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
can :edit, Appointment, office_id: employee.office_ids
```

Comment: Wow, that was amazingly simple. Would you mind pointing me towards the place in the documentation that you found this? Thanks again!

Comment: Thats not from the documentation, it's just out of my mind. Take a look at the cancan or cancancan wiki maybe.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. I actually didn't even know that you could call `.office_ids` on a `has_many` relationship, so that's very helpful!